# how to get button value to another react component?

Tags: reactjs, button, react-forms

so i have a form component having button array,
though i used icons in it with value attribute. just like below.

```
<button value={'admin'} onClick={(e)=> handleClick(e.target.value)}>
      <FaUserSecret classname="text-lg" />
</button>
```

in handleClick function `e.target.value` is returning icon instead of `admin`.

Thanks in advance .

I tried to pass `e` as parametter and use its value in function but still same.

Comment: Show `handleClick`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.currentTarget.getAttribute("value")` method to get the admin value assigned to the button.

[CodeSandbox code reference](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-wozniak-sccu3g)

Difference b/w e.target and e.currentTarget - [difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)

Comment: Hi @warl0ck sry for making it complicated. its working `but`    
***it need text inside button not just icon or else it returns null value***     
[updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-sky-g49tj0?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: you can get the value from `e.currentTarget` see the SO question mentioned in the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate or share more code with us. Cause I tried your given code and it's working fine. I am getting **'admin'** as the output.

```
    <div className='App'>
      <button value={'admin'} onClick={(e)=> console.log(e.target.value)}>
     Click
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @blackwatch021 the issue is that i used icons in button body instead of plane text
as well it is treating that icon as button value not `value={'admin'}` attribute
so **getting null value instead of admin**  

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<button value={'admin'} onClick={e => handleClick(e.target.value)}>
      <FaUserSecret classname="text-lg" />
</button>
```

You're not supposed to use parenthesis around "e".

Comment: Not really, parenthesis are optional with arrow functions if there is one parameter

Comment: yep we can skip parenthesis, it just make code easier to understood