# jQuery Index returns incorrect results

Tags: html, jquery

I have a `ul` with a number of `li's` which contain an `img` tag and a p tag in them and I am trying to find the index of the `li` on click like so :

```js
$("li").on("click", (e) => {
  console.log($(e.target).parent().index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Hindu</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Muslim</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Christian</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I get odd numbers when I click, I've check the function and it is selecting the `li`.

I tried selecting the parent `li` and logging it's index but I get incorrect indexes.

Comment: "*I am trying to find the index of the li*"  then why are you selecting the `li`'s .parent()?  Add some debugging: `console.log(e.target.nodeName)`

Comment: target is what you click on, it is not the element that the event is attached to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property

Comment: `console.log($(e.currentTarget).index());`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you're clicking on the `<li>`, sometimes you're clicking on an element *within* the `<li>`.  This will change what `e.target` is and therefore what `.parent()` refers to.  (In the stack snippet, the difference is observed by clicking on the text vs. clicking on the bullet point.)

Instead of using `.parent()`, use `.closest('li')`.  That way the logic is always looking at the `<li>` for the index:

```js
$("li").on("click", (e) => {
  console.log($(e.target).closest('li').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Hindu</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Muslim</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Christian</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: or you just use `console.log($(e.currentTarget).index());`

Answer (score 0):

The target isn't always what you think it is. Sometimes it's the list item, so the index will refer to that.

```js
$("li").on("click", e => {
  console.log(e.target);
  console.log($(e.target).parent().index());
});
```

```css
li {
  background: pink;
}

img,
p {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="">
    <p>Hindu</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="">
    <p>Muslim</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="">
    <p>Christian</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```